# How to use Inteface as a field type in Request Body model class in Rest API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interface, jackson

We have a Java SpringBoot API endpoint and we pass a RequestBody of NotifyMoiChanges class type. In NotifyMoiChanges  model class we have one filed which is Interface type.

**Endpoint snippet :**

```
@PostMapping("/notifyMOIChanges")
public ResponseEntity<Void> notifyMOIChangesPost(@RequestBody NotifyMoiChanges notifyMoiChanges) {
        logger.info("Received notifyMOIChanges request.");
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
```

**RequestBody Model snippet:**

```
public class NotifyMoiChanges {
  @JsonProperty("moiChanges")
  @Valid
  private List<MoiChange> moiChanges = new ArrayList<MoiChange>();
  ..... other attributes
}

public class MoiChange   {
      @JsonProperty("operation")
      private String operation = null;   //operation value can be "Type1" or "Type2"
    
      @JsonProperty("value")
      private OneOfMoiChangeValue value = null;   //value filed can be mapped with any of the OneOfMoiChangeValue Interface implentations  Type1MoiChangeValue or Type2MoiChangeValue.
    }
```

OneOfMoiChangeValue  is an Interface which has two implementations Type1MoiChangeValue & Type2MoiChangeValue.

Now when I pass a RequestBody based on the 'operation' filed data I have to map the 'value' field of Request Body with any of the Interface implementations Type1MoiChangeValue or Type2MoiChangeValue.

```
public interface OneOfMoiChangeValue {

}
```

**Type1MoiChangeValue:**

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.SpringCodegen", date = "2021-11-16T11:51:46.436+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]")
public class Type1MoiChangeValue  extends ArrayList<Type2MoiChangeValue > implements OneOfMoiChangeValue {

  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(super.hashCode());
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class Type1MoiChangeValue {\n");
    sb.append("    ").append(toIndentedString(super.toString())).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }
}
```

**Type2MoiChangeValue:**

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.SpringCodegen", date = "2021-11-16T11:51:46.436+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]")
public class Type2MoiChangeValue extends HashMap<String, Object> implements OneOfMoiChangeValue {

  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(super.hashCode());
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class Type2MoiChangeValue {\n");
    sb.append("    ").append(toIndentedString(super.toString())).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }
}
```

We are using jackson parser. How can I do it. Please advice!

Comment: Can you please add the code for `OneOfMoiChangeValue`, `Type1MoiChangeValue` and `Type2MoiChangeValue`? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JoãoDias , I have updated the full code. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to to a couple of changes in your code and as a consequence in your request body. The first is to update `OneOfMoiChangeValue` with a couple of Jackson annotations so that it can know how to handle the different subtypes based on a property named `operation`:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

import static com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY;
import static com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = NAME, include = PROPERTY, property = "operation")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Type1MoiChangeValue.class, name = "Type1"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Type2MoiChangeValue.class, name = "Type2")
})
public interface OneOfMoiChangeValue {

}
```

This means that you no longer need the `operation` property in `MoiChange`:

```java
public class MoiChange {
      @JsonProperty("value")
      private OneOfMoiChangeValue value = null;   //value filed can be mapped with any of the OneOfMoiChangeValue Interface implentations  Type1MoiChangeValue or Type2MoiChangeValue.
}
```

Instead, it must be sent alongside all the other properties of `OneOfMoiChangeValue`, so something along the following lines:

```json
{
    "moiChanges": 
    [
        {
            "value": {
                "operation": "Type1",
                (...)
            }    
        },
        {
            "value": {
                "operation": "Type2",
                (...)
            }    
        },
        (...)
    ]
}
```

Comment: This looks good. Let me try it and update you.

Comment: Hi @João , I just now came to know I cannot change the request body and add the extra field 'operation' inside the 'value' attribute as the Req Body is considered as standard format and don't have permission to manipulate it. So without adding any extra field in request body can we do it?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. The only option could be a custom deserializer. I really like how people think that software is a set in stone thing and that changes can't be done in any way (I know this is not your decision ;) ).

Comment: Yes agree with you. :)
 We have to use custom deserializer in this case. I am new to it. So trying to write some if I can do it.

Comment: Hi @João Dias, I have written a custom deserializer as you said and it worked. Also the suggestion you have in the answer will work most of the cases as we can generally pass the extra field in the json. I am accepting your solution as it was correct. Thanks for your help to resolving it :)

Comment: You are welcome! Consider also adding your custom deserializer as an answer and accept it ;)